# How to use a boolean to pass data to table, using the pre-made laravel register set-up

Tags: laravel, boolean, migration

newbie here. So I have been editing the built in user-table created with vue --auth. So far, I have added my own text columns which was easy enough, but now I am faced with using a boolean. I have looked everywhere and I cannot find a simple way to pass data through a checkbox form to the table.

**Here is my migration file:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->mediumText('bio');
            //$table->boolean('is_expert')->default(false);
            //$table->tinyInteger('is_customer'); 
            //$table->binary('photo')->nullable();          
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**The commented out boolean is what I want to use**

So I run this code (after removing the //)

Then I need to create a form in my register.blade.php.

**here's what it looks like so far:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="first-name" type="text" class="form-control @error('first-name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name" required>

                                @error('first-name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="last-name" type="text" class="form-control @error('last-name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name" required>

                                @error('last-name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="bio" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Bio') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="bio" type="text" class="form-control @error('bio') is-invalid @enderror" name="bio" required>

                                @error('bio')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**more content after here but similar text forms**

**and here is my controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'bio' => ['required', 'string', 'max:200'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],

            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],

            'bio' => $data['bio'],

            'email' => $data['email'],
            
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

}
```

**Apologies for the amount of code pasted here! my question is. How would I set out the form in the register.blade file and then, what will I need in the controller? Will I also need to enter anything into the model. Once again apologies for the dumb question and vague details, I couldn't find the answer to this question when looking**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand. If you want to give user a possibility of setting if he is an expert during registration, this is what you need to do:

**View:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_expert"></input>
```

**Controller:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],

        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],

        'bio' => $data['bio'],

        'email' => $data['email'],
  
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

        'is_expert' => $data['is_expert']
    ]);
}
```

**User Model:**
If you want to use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) you need to add "is_expert" to "fillable" property in your User model. Probably it will look something like this:

```
class User extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'email', 'password', 'is_expert'];
```

But note that this is big security gap - password need to be specified by another way e.g. "$user->setPassword();" and then "$user->save();"
Also remember to uncomment "is_expert" in your migration file.